# Em R, existe diferença entre aspas duplas e simples?

Tags: r, string, característica-linguagem

Estou iniciando meu aprendizado em R e gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre criar strings usando aspas simples ou duplas. Por exemplo:

```r
texto1 <- "isso é um texto"
texto2 <- 'isso é um texto'
```

Existe alguma diferença entre os casos acima? Existe alguma situação que você é obrigado a usar aspas simples ou duplas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Quotes.html), não há diferença para maioria das aplicações, embora aspas duplas sejam preferidas:

> Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and character constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are normally only used to delimit character constants containing double quotes.

Entretanto, há casos especiais em que a ordem utilizada para declarar as aspas pode levar a erros de interpretação do programa. Mas nos casos tradicionais de utilização das aspas, como declaração de strings simples, podem ser criados utilizando `'` ou `"` sem precisar de maiores cuidados.

```r
print("Ola, Mundo!")
## "Ola, Mundo!"

print('Ola, Mundo!')
## "Ola, Mundo!"

print("'Ola, Mundo!'")
## "'Ola, Mundo!'"

print('"Ola, Mundo!"')
## "\"Ola, Mundo!\""

print(""Ola, Mundo!"")
## Error: unexpected symbol in "print(""Ola"

print(''Ola, Mundo!'')
## Error: unexpected symbol in "print(''Ola"
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: Disponha! Questões bem formuladas são um prazer em responder.